# How to data_color() a specific cell with gt() package in R

Tags: r, gt

I would like to highlight specific elements of tables. The `gt` package produces great tables and `data_color()` brings some light in the whiteness.

```
library(gt)
head(mtcars) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = c("cyl"),
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c("red", "orange"),
      domain = c(3, 10)
    ))
```

[image]

But how can I highlight a single cell, e.g. the first element of `cyl`? Sometimes I can manipulate the `domain` option for numeric values, but 6 appears multiple times. I tried this suggestion [R gt package -background coloring a single cell, when it equals a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58214724/r-gt-package-background-coloring-a-single-cell-when-it-equals-a-certain-value) via `tab_style()` which does not work for me.

```
head(mtcars) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
       style = cell_fill(color = 'grey'),
       locations = cells_body(
       columns = vars(cyl), 
       rows = cyl > 5
    ))
```

I'd like to adress a simple element instead of a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index by position: `rows = 1`.

```r
head(mtcars) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = 'grey'),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c(cyl), 
      rows = 1
    ))
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I didn't saw this option. Thank you